# How to get one unique scroll with infinite-scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm facing a lot of problem using the library infinite-scroll for Angular. The working solution with the "scroll" method invoked is:

```
    <div infiniteScroll style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto" [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" (scrolled)="onScroll()" [scrollWindow]="false">
  <h2>Photo reps</h2>
  <div *ngIf="emptyList" style="text-align: center;">
    <img  src="../../../assets/images/noElements.gif">
    <p>No elements found</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!emptyList" fxLayout="row wrap">
    <div *ngFor="let user of photoReps" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.sm="50">
    ......
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>
  <p *ngIf="noMoreItems">No more items</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that with this solution I've got a double scroll-bar (the one of the root/page and the one of the div). This is good for mouse-device, but not for smartphone etc...
The correct solution is the one without the overflow-y property (auto), but the method doesn't trig/fire the scrolled; why?
Am I wrong with something? This is the link: https://bcctest.it/photoReps

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
div#rightside-content-hold {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to your css.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code?

Comment: To remove the second scrollbar

Comment: It doesn't work, but should be let scroll all the element in the sub-list?